# enumeration in python for the combinations

Tags: python

I have my input like this:

```
T A G C  
2
```

I want my output like this.

```
TT
TA
TG
TC
AT
AA
AG
AC
GT
GA
GG
GC
CT
CA
CG
CC
```

If i give 3 in the input at place of 2 the the output should be like:

```
TTT
TTA
TTG
TTC
TAT
TAA
TAG
TAC
...
...
and so on....
```

I have written code but i dont know what to do after this:

```
data=open('D:\python\input.txt')
a=data.read().split('\n')
result=[]
symbol=a[0]
integer=a[1]

if integer==0:
   result.append(None)
for s in symbol:
```

I dont know what to do after this ....

Comment: can you tell me where is the duplicate ques ??

Comment: It gets added to a yellow box at the top of your question. But it's also right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), with a `repeat` of `n`:

```
from itertools import product

n = 2
l = ["T","A","G","C"]

for prod in (product(l,repeat=n)): 
    print("".join(prod))
TT
TA
TG
TC
AT
AA
AG
AC
GT
GA
GG
GC
CT
CA
CG
CC
```

You should also use `with` to open your files which closes them automatically and either use raw string `r` for your file paths or `/'s`. You need to split each line into individual elements, you can then use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` to join all the elements and create the product:

```
from itertools import product, chain
n = 3
with open(r'D:\python\input.txt') as data:  # <- raw string "r" 
    symbols = chain.from_iterable(x.split() for x in data)
    for prod in product(symbols,repeat=n):
        print("".join(prod))

TTT
TTA
TTG
TTC
TAT
TAA
.......................
```

Without chain and a generator expressions we can use `list.extend` t create a single list of all items:

```
with open(r'D:\python\input.txt') as data:
    symbols = []
    for line in data:
        symbols.extend(line.split())
    for prod in product(symbols, repeat=n):
        print("".join(prod))
```

Comment: i checked that answer but it was different. and the answer which i got now .. in this you have given the answer only for T A G C.. but it can be more...

Comment: I am saving it in the list but not getting the answer

Comment: @shahbazkhan, yes because  it is an example. I  don't know what  data you have so kind of hard of do anything else, if you showed exactly what the file content looked looked like it would help

Comment: i have given it at the starting of my ques.. how my input file look like...it is a text file..

Comment: well if it all looks like that then the edit will work

Comment: can u tell me what is the function of "chain" here.

Comment: because we split each line we would have a list of lists of we just used the generator expression. `chain.from_iterable` "chains" all the elements  together, if you called `list` on symbols you would see a single list of all items chained together